# Do I have to care about indent when HTML is generated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As you know, if we use the form helper something like `select_tag` all the generated HTML's indent comes back to the very left.

Then generated HTML source looks ugly.
How do you handle this problem?

and does it matter to SEO?

Comment: Unless you're worried that someone will judge you when they look at your source, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

As long as its valid HTML then search engines won't care about your whitespace/layout. Infact they can handle even invalid mark up to be honest. You don't get bonus points for having a clear HTML layout though I'm afraid.

Nice layouts make development/debugging easier and you should at least try to make it look pretty. But then using code generators like this it not always possible.

Focus on getting it working well and worry about prettying it up later if you have time ;)

I'm sure there is a way to modify the output if Rails is still as awesome as it used to be last time I had a play with it.

Comment: Arguably, it shouldn't really matter for debugging either if you use something like Firebug to inspect your markup.

Comment: Careful, Firebug will only show you the DOM that the browser has loading in memory, not the HTML you sent down the wire. Try leaving out a closing div and you will see what I mean. The DOM will guess where it should be but only by eye balling you HTML can you see/work out where the missing div is. Always check the original source

Answer (score 0):

I use the `erector` gem to create my views, `erector` is basically an HTML-DSL in plain ruby which, among other things, allows to `pretty_print` your HTML. This is usually just done during development, as the additional whitespace would just increase the page size, burn bandwidth and slightly slow down the browser.

For this reason I cannot imagine that search-engines care at all. They just might have to do a little more work, so they might rank it a little lower, but I even doubt that much. They might care for valid HTML, that is another advantage of `erector` (and other templating languages as HAML and the like).